# How to inject all Github environment-specific variables from vars to env context?

Tags: github, github-actions

Environment variables from GitHub Environments are available in the [vars context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context).

Sometimes you could have 5-6 variables in the `vars` context, and you would like to have them injected into the `env` context to use them in the steps. Is there an automated or easy way?

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this with [`toJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```yaml
- name: Set vars to env
  env:
    VARS_JSON: ${{ toJSON(vars) }}
  run: |
    echo "$VARS_JSON" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Check env vars
  run: |
    echo "VAR1=$VAR1"
    echo "VAR2=$VAR2"
```

Sample ouptut:

[image: vars_to_env]