# Convert name value pair from JSON to windows environment variables - PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, github-actions

We are moving to GitHub actions (I'm new to actions) and would like to convert the current $json into environment name value pairs. I would like to extract and Name-Value and set/export as windows environment variables. Below is the extract and output of my code. Appreciate any help!

```
name: Check Build Properties JSON Var File
        id: read-json
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          $jsonfilePath = Get-ChildItem ${{github.workspace }}\buildtools -Recurse | where {$_.name -match 'buildproperties.json'} |  % { $_.FullName }
          echo "The Value of the declared variable filepath is:- $jsonfilePath"
          #$json = Get-Content $jsonfilePath | ConvertFrom-Json
          $json = Get-Content $jsonfilePath -Raw
          $JsonParameters = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
```

This is the current output

```
the contents of the RAW JSON file from buildTools is: {
  "UPACKPATH": "C:\\Users\\builduser\\upack.exe",
  "NUGETPATH": "C:\\Users\\builduser\\Nuget.exe",
  "NugetPackageUrl": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json",
  "SemVer": '1.0.0.0',
  "PackagePortal": false
}
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691648/how-to-inject-all-github-environment-specific-variables-from-vars-to-env-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you might [Iterate over PSObject properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37688708/1701026) and use the [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables#using-the-systemenvironment-methods) method:

```
$Json = '{
  "UPACKPATH": "C:\\Users\\builduser\\upack.exe",
  "NUGETPATH": "C:\\Users\\builduser\\Nuget.exe",
  "NugetPackageUrl": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json",
  "SemVer": "1.0.0.0",
  "PackagePortal": false
}'
```

```
$Parameters = Convertfrom-Json $Json
$Parameters.PSObject.Properties |Foreach-Object {
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($_.Name, $_.Value)
}
```