# Modify appsettings.json in github actions

Tags: .net, github, github-actions

I want to on change the appsettings.json values on publishing the repository through Github Action when building and deploying the .net6 project.

In bitbucket there exists things like bbenv that can modify appsettings file. In Github we want to take the secrets and variable from Github environment and replace variables in the appsettings file and put the environment variable inside.

Is this possible or do i have to switch and use AWS Secret manager or similar to make it work ?
Example:
appsettings.json

```
{
  "secret1":"My-Secret-value"
}
```

Environment variable in Github

```
secret1=VerySecurePassword
```

Comment: You can store your password as an [encrypted secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets?tool=webui) and then use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to replace it. `jq` is preinstalled on GHA hosted runners.

Comment: @Azeem do i need to do the secrets one by one or can i retrieve all secrets and replace ? Have about 30 secrets in github

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve all the secrets at once e.g. `toJson(secrets)` and then loop through KV pairs and replace those in the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691648/how-to-inject-all-github-environment-specific-variables-from-vars-to-env-context and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476536/how-to-find-and-replace-multiple-field-values-using-jq.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the following action prior to deploying the artifacts to azure.

You can specify multiple files and it is supported with wildcard entries too.

The environment variable key must be specified with dot separated heirarchy.

```
#substitute production appsettings entries to appsettings json file
- name: App Settings Variable Substitution
  uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
  with:
    files: '${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp/appsettings.json'
  env:
    ConnectionStrings.Default: ${{ secrets.SOME_CONNECTION_STRING }}
    App.ServerRootAddress: ${{ env.SERVER_ROOT_ADDRESS }}
```