# How to send a multiline string parameter as a command via AWS SSM command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, cicd, aws-ssm

I am trying to create an .env file on my remote AWS instance using a Github Workflow file.
I am using the following command to set the contents of the .env file:

```
  - name: Setting Github env vars to variable
    run: |
      echo "DEV_ENV_VAR<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo "$VARS_JSON" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' >> $GITHUB_ENV
      echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

This creates a multiline string of data that needs to be put into an .env file.
I am then trying to do the following command:

```
unbuffer aws ssm start-session --parameters command="cd /web/app; git pull; yarn install; echo ${{ env.DEV_ENV_VAR }} >> .env; yarn build;" --target '${{ env.MY_TARGET }}' --document-name "AWS-StartInteractiveCommand";
```

But it doesn't seem to write anything into the .env file, and gives a syntax error if I am using a `-e` parameter for `echo` command.
How do I correctly achieve sending the multiline string in the parameters? Is there perhaps another way of achieving my goal?

My whole workflow file looks like this right now:

```
name: Update Frontend

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.operating-system }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        operating-system: [ubuntu-20.04]
    environment: dev
    env:
      DEPLOY_USERNAME: ubuntu
      DEPLOY_SERVER: (my AWS instance ID here)
      DEPLOY_PATH: /deploy/path
      VARS_JSON: ${{ toJSON(vars) }}
    steps:
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
        with:
          aws-region: eu-west-1
          role-to-assume: ${{ secrets.AWS_ROLE_TO_ASSUME }}
      - name: Setting Github env vars to variable
        run: |
          echo "DEV_ENV_VAR<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "$VARS_JSON" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Running commands on server
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update;
          sudo apt-get install expect -qq > /dev/null;
          echo "Starting execution of commands";
          unbuffer aws ssm start-session --parameters command="cd ${{ env.DEPLOY_PATH }}; git pull; yarn install --frozen-lockfile; echo ${{ env.DEV_ENV_VAR }} >> .env; yarn build; pm2 restart all;" --target '${{ env.DEPLOY_SERVER }}' --document-name "AWS-StartInteractiveCommand";
```

Comment: Why not just create the file instead of setting it as an env var? Is the next command under the same job? Please add your workflow keeping its structure intact (only the relevant steps).

Comment: I can't send a file using aws-ssm command, can I?

Comment: Added the whole workflow, as suggested.

Comment: Not sure about that. Given your question, you can simply create an `.env` in one line. Next step should be able to see that. That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: With `echo "$VARS_JSON" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' >> .env`, it'll only be one line and you don't have add `echo ${{ env.DEV_ENV_VAR }} >> .env` in the next step.

Comment: Well, creating an .env file is exactly what I am trying to do. It's just the contents of the file are a multiline string, so I need to pass that somehow.

Comment: `echo "$VARS_JSON" | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\(.[$k])"' >> .env` will only create the .env file in the workflow instance of Git. I need it on the AWS server, thus I am passing it via params.

Comment: Are you able to create an `.env` file with one line?

Comment: Meaning adding it to the last line where I pass parameters to aws-ssm?

Comment: Just test with `unbuffer aws ssm start-session --parameters command="echo '${{ env.DEV_ENV_VAR }}' >> .env"`.

Comment: Also, from the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-param-runcommand.html), there's this `commands`, not `command`. I'm not well-versed with `aws ssm`. Not sure if that's fine or a typo.

Comment: @Azeem The document passed is a noninteractive one and not the run shell script. They differ in the command or commands parameters allowed.