Mirror environment and secrets to a subscript
As far as I know, in GitHub Actions I can access environment variables like so ${{ vars.<> }} and secrets like so ${{ secrets.<> }}.
I want a subscript (say, write all of them to a single file) to have access to all of them automatically, without having to edit the script each time I edit the list of variables.
Is there a way to access and iterate over all the environment variables and secrets?
As of now, I have to do it explicitly one by one (and access them with env: as well), and this produces bugs if I forget or if there are changes.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75691648/how-to-inject-all-github-environment-specific-variables-from-vars-to-env-context. This should be the same. Use toJson to dump the required context and iterate as needed, maybe using jq, bash, etc.
